# OSB stage-level error handler missing

Tags: osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have developed an OSB 12.2 pipeline template, which includes an error handler attached to a stage that performs schema validation. When a validation fault is raised, the intent is to catch it in the stage handler, log the validation details, and raise a generic error.

At the service level, I have defined another error handler which is meant to catch the generic error thrown from the validation error handler and perform some other actions.

In JDeveloper, I have generated a pipeline from the template, and I can see that my handlers are both present in the pipeline and have the actions I have defined. I export the project to a JAR and successfully deploy via the service bus console, but when I look at the stage-level error handler in the console's pipeline viewer, none of my defined actions are present.

[Image: Handler stage logic is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJc3x.png)

Predictably, any validation error is *not* caught at the stage level but goes straight to the service-level handler, which is not what I want.

If I start out with a regular non-template pipeline and code all the same actions and handlers, all is well. The error handler logic is present.

[Image: Handler stage logic is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn0iN.png)

Is there some trick to getting stage-level actions in template-linked pipelines to deploy and work correctly?

Comment: Have you checked what the XML of the proxy looks like in JDev, and again inside the JAR, and again when you import into console and export it again? Might help to narrow down which step is removing the handler.

Comment: I unpacked the JAR produced by JDeveloper and can see that the stage handler is present in my pipeline template. That suggests to me that the handler logic is not being merged into the linked pipeline when I import the JAR using SB console; however, when I export the project from SB console and look in the JAR, the pipeline template contains my stage handler logic, as well.

It's only the deployed, merged pipeline that "thinks" it doesn't have the handler logic.

Comment: I guess the next thing is to look at alternate ways of importing the jar (WLST  comes to mind, since OEPE probably has its own issues) to see whether there's a bug specific to sbconsole. If so, that's your workaround. If not, maybe install the latest patchset and see if there's a fix there.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but I notice that when I unlink the pipeline from the template, the error handler from the template is not merged into the pipeline. So it appears that it's not just a problem at sbconsole deployment time.

After hours of digging, I did find where there's a bug logged with Oracle for the problem I've described, but it doesn't appear that there's been much movement toward a patch. I guess the workaround is to either go through contortions in the template's service-level handler, or use unlinked pipelines so that stage-level handlers work.